# How should I retrieve just the names and emails of ApplicationUser in .net core API

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm kinda new so I apologize if I'm not using the correct terminology.

Basically I'm building a .net core web app with an AngularJs component in the frontend to retrieve and display the results from my API's JSON get request.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
    [HttpGet("Clients")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> AllClients()
    {
        IEnumerable<AppUser> Clients = await _userManagerService.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Client");

        return Json(listErrorMsg(Clients));
    }
```

The problem i'm having is that the API sends EVERY column of every user, as expected.

```
[
  {
   "firstName": "Client2",
    "lastName": "2",
    "residentialAddress": null,
    "residentialSuburb": null,
    "residentialPostCode": null,
    "residentialCity": null,
    "residentialstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "postalAddress": null,
    "postalSuburb": null,
    "postalPostCode": null,
    "postalCity": null,
    "postalstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "lastSync": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "accountCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastVisited": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "client": null,
    "clientID": null,
    "id": "2075c598-5bc3-4f74-a843-ac41e4d0bc36",
    "userName": "Client2",
    "normalizedUserName": "CLIENT2",
    "email": null,
    "normalizedEmail": null,
    "emailConfirmed": true,
    "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAELFKxfP2giuEtg8+M4q7Pu2+lpGBDOwWkajL/KnKTGQ5gkBnYdZZ/tdtpNnQyyRjpA==",
    "securityStamp": "4146b78a-8710-4951-90c9-da17af4e0d95",
    "concurrencyStamp": "245bdd70-8d46-4e01-a512-2bb124fac42e",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
    "lockoutEnd": null,
    "lockoutEnabled": true,
    "accessFailedCount": 0,
    "roles": [],
    "claims": [],
    "logins": []
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Client1",
    "lastName": "1",
    "residentialAddress": null,
    "residentialSuburb": null,
    "residentialPostCode": null,
    "residentialCity": null,
    "residentialstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "postalAddress": null,
    "postalSuburb": null,
    "postalPostCode": null,
    "postalCity": null,
    "postalstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "lastSync": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "accountCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastVisited": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "client": null,
    "clientID": null,
    "id": "3466054a-42b5-4185-a677-4bf110dea420",
    "userName": "Client1",
    "normalizedUserName": "CLIENT1",
    "email": null,
    "normalizedEmail": null,
    "emailConfirmed": true,
    "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAELWrulfO5YQudMggGpvXPos54Faie7PxOac1/Yjy9PjY4PuSpb6Kpqfn85a4ABbVyg==",
    "securityStamp": "47370050-772b-4365-8238-ebacebeea802",
    "concurrencyStamp": "c072bf2e-9d21-4c66-95da-552fa0af50ca",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
    "lockoutEnd": null,
    "lockoutEnabled": true,
    "accessFailedCount": 0,
    "roles": [],
    "claims": [],
    "logins": []
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Client0",
    "lastName": "0",
    "residentialAddress": null,
    "residentialSuburb": null,
    "residentialPostCode": null,
    "residentialCity": null,
    "residentialstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "postalAddress": null,
    "postalSuburb": null,
    "postalPostCode": null,
    "postalCity": null,
    "postalstateTerritory": "NULL",
    "lastSync": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "accountCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastVisited": "2017-05-09T21:53:42.5080226",
    "client": null,
    "clientID": null,
    "id": "a504e831-9524-480e-b5a0-745891da65b4",
    "userName": "Client0",
    "normalizedUserName": "CLIENT0",
    "email": "fake@fake.com",
    "normalizedEmail": "FAKE@FAKE.COM",
    "emailConfirmed": true,
    "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEOvIdZDsXnYt+ToSYaKXmsnNSrfgwjy/Or4vM4pMo5gx45YFrxiZAig9a4ZEatg9KA==",
    "securityStamp": "a4dcce55-660e-4d06-b2ed-ac065b6c0552",
    "concurrencyStamp": "0b4759b5-e0a5-4a08-a3af-595360f8e30b",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
    "lockoutEnd": "2017-05-02T01:55:03.7282498+00:00",
    "lockoutEnabled": true,
    "accessFailedCount": 0,
    "roles": [],
    "claims": [],
    "logins": []
  }
]
```

However, I only want a few of fields to be sent through the API like name and email just to protect user data.

```
{
"firstName": "Client2",
"lastName": "2",
"id": "2075c598-5bc3-4f74-a843-ac41e4d0bc36",
"userName": "Client2",
"normalizedUserName": "CLIENT2",
"email": null,
"normalizedEmail": null,
"phoneNumber": null,
},
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just selecting the values from the list as an anonymous object

```
return Json(listErrorMsg(Clients.Select(a=> new { 
    firstName = a.firstName,
    lastName = a.lastName,
    id = a.id,
    userName = a.userName,
    normalizedUserName = a.normalizedUserName,
    email = a.email,
    normalizedEmail = a.normalizedEmail,
    phoneNumber = a.phoneNumber
}));
```